# How can I get a PNG from a byte Array (2 bytes/pixel)?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I have a byte array where my data is stored with two bytes per pixel. I now want to have a PNG from this data. I've found a great code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368003/java-how-to-create-png-image-from-a-byte):

```
byte[] aByteArray = {0xa,0x2,0xf,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff};
int width = 1;
int height = 2;

DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(aByteArray, aByteArray.length);

//3 bytes per pixel: red, green, blue
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, 3 * width, 3, new int[] {0, 1, 2}, (Point)null);
ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(ColorModel.getRGBdefault().getColorSpace(), false, true, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE); 
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, true, null);

ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("image.png"));
```

Here the author uses 3 bytes per pixel. So my Question is: How can I make this code work if my Byte Array has 2 bytes per pixel?

UPDATE:
The data is gray scaled, sry I didnt konw that before... So there is no need to get an colored image. So you know who to get an gray scaled image from this byte array?

Comment: First, we would need to know how are those two bytes encoded... would it be 15 bit color? This two bytes per pixel image is something that you created, or are you taking it from somewhere?

Comment: I get this two bytes per Pixel array, it is encoded with 12 bits_per_pixel, but it is rounded to 2 bytes per pixel

Comment: Then you will need to do some bit shifting on the pixel to extract the groups of 3 bits into separate bytes...

Comment: @conryyy It would help if updated your question with an example of the actual data you receive. And specify that it is 12 bits/pixel, 0-padded to 16 bit (if this is indeed the case). I assume the data is gray scale, is this correct? If not, specify what it is. And finally, please don't answer with another comment, instead update the question text as per the SO guidelines. :-)

Comment: @conryyy Follow-up question, as PNG does not directly support 12 bits/pixel (only 8 or 16): Is it okay to lose information, and truncate the image to 8 bits/pixel, or do you want to scale the values up to 16 bit/pixel?

Comment: thx for your reply guys, I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have to give this code 3 bytes per pixel, so it gets the three colors of RGB. If you want to do it like that with only Green and Blue or another combination, you should set a default value for the third one... But I'm not 100% sure.